# HTTP Status 404 - /temp/j_spring_security_check error. Any idea?

Tags: jsp, spring-security

I am trying to implement security in my application using Spring Security and JSP. However, I am getting the above error.  And I looked on the internet and there is one article where it says that we get this error message when the login path url has another level, for example ‘auth/login’, which is my case.
My login path is  http://localhost:8080/temp/login/login.mvc.  The proposed solution was to add a '/' in front of j_spring_security_check'in the login.jsp.
This will ensure that Spring correctly processes login using the url. 
However, I am still getting the same error.

Below is my login.jsp, spring-security.xml and controller codes.

Login.jsp:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html id="login">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><spring:message code="login.title" /></title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container spaceless">                                       
        <form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
            <table id="albums" cellspacing="0px" style="width: 100%;">                      
                <tr>
                    <td width="32%"  align="right" style="padding-right:13px;"><spring:message code="login.email" /></td>
                    <td style="padding-right: 22px;"><input type="text" name="j_username" size="29" style="width: 100%;"></td>
                </tr>       

                                            <tr class="spaceUnderLess">
                                                <td width="32%" align="right" style="padding-right:13px;"><spring:message code="login.password" /></td>
                                                <td style="padding-right: 22px;"><input type="password" name="j_password" size="29" style="width: 100%;"></td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr class="spaceUnderLess" >
                                                <td width="32%" ></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value">
                                                    <label for="checkbox_id"><spring:message code="login.remember" /></label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>   

                                            <tr class="spaceUnderLess" >
                                                <td colspan="2" align="right" style="padding-right: 19px;">
                                                    <span style="padding-right:13px;" class="colorText"><spring:message code="login.forget.password" /></span>
                                                    <button  class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="submit" style="width:120px;"><spring:message code="login.btn.access" /></button>
                                                </td>                       
                                            </tr>                   
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

spring-security.xml

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
          <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
          </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.mvc")
public ModelAndView getLogin(Model model) {     
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

Or maybe I need to add anything in the web.xml??
web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- Le dispatcher de servlet de spring -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TempMvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:applicationContext.xml,
                classpath:TempMvc-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TempMvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mvc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context-webservice.xml,classpath:applicationContext.xml,
                classpath:TempMvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <!-- Le dispatcher de servlet de cxf -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocationCXf</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:application-context-webservice.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/login/login.mvc</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    
</web-app>
```

Comment: You forgot to add spring security filter in your `web.xml`

Comment: Yes but when I add security filters, I get a 404 error.  Any idea where could the problem be?

Comment: are you using /temp context for the app? can you access directly the url from the browser i.e. `http://localhost:8080/app/j_spring_security_check`?

Comment: Nope I can't. I get a 404 error.